# Как в magento сделать Middle Name/Initial обязательным полем?

Tags: magento

Выставляю в настройках - "Требуется значения" - да. Но все-равно не работает.
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1):

В magento 1.x поле с frontend_label "Middle Name/Initial" и attribute_code "middlename" существует в двух экземплярах для разных EAV таблиц: customer и customer_address. Посмотреть можно запросом к базе

```
SELECT eav_entity_type.entity_type_id, entity_type_code, attribute_code, attribute_id, frontend_label, is_required FROM eav_attribute, eav_entity_type WHERE attribute_code = 'middlename' and eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id;
```

Сделано это для того, чтобы при удалении пользователя из таблицы customer сохранились данные об адресе доставки в логах. Возможно вы изменили обязательность значения не той таблицы? Выставить необходимую вам обязательность заполнения можно с помощью запроса к базе. Для customer:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 6;
```

Для customer_address:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 21;
```

Вероятнее всего attribute_id у вас будут теми же, но все-таки проверьте по первому SELECT`у. Удачи вам с magento!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! С magento удача не помешает точно)